MongoDB format exception 'BookID' does not match any field or property
I have a mongoDB database called BookStore that has a single collection called Books. The Schema of this collection is 'BookID', 'Title', and 'Authors'

I have a dotNet api running that was connecting to it. It was running properly but I changed the model and now I'm running into issues. My book model looks like this.
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

namespace BookStoreApi.Models;

public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? BookID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Authors { get; set; } = null!;
}

When trying to hit this API, I get the following error.

This is confusing because it seems like my model should match my schema. So I don't get why it's saying 'BookID' doesn't match any field or property.
I know based on This answer I can add [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] to my Book model and my api call will work but that seems to be ignoring the problem. I don't get why things seem out of sync.

i think in the model it identifies BookID as the _id.  can you try adding a Id field with the annotations you have put for BookID and use a seperate property for BookID

Hey good call! That worked and I was able to remove IgnoreExtraElements attribute on my book class. If you put this in the form of an answer I'll accept it when the timer allows me.

Quoting the docs

The Id Member
By convention, a public member called Id, id, or _id will be used as the identifier. You can be specific about this using the BsonIdAttribute.
public class MyClass 
{
    [BsonId]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


So in your case the BookID field in model is mapped to the _id in Mongo. Since your BookID is a separate field itself you will have to create separate Id and BookID fields
Something like this
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string BookID { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public string Authors { get; set; } = null!;
}

